# Saveurl with a parameter

Tags: apex, visualforce, urlhacking, redirect

I have a visualforce page that has a list of opportunity products and in this there is a column where you can either create a new related item or lookup an existing item (of a custom object). Looking up an existing item is working fine, but creating a new one and returing to this page is not working for me.

When creating a new item, I have it currently working so that after clicking save on the standard edit page using saveurl, it returns to my visual force page. The next thing I need to happen is that there needs to be an id of the opportunity product passed with the saveurl so that I know which opportunity product to add this item I just created to.

Here is the section of my visualforce page where I create the parameter:

> ```
>  <apex:column headerValue="">    
>             <apex:commandButton action="{!onCreateNew}" value="Create New Item">
>              <apex:param value="{!a.Id}" assignTo="{!aID}" name="aID"/>
>             </apex:commandButton>              
>  </apex:column>
> ```

Here is the section of my controller where I create the page reference:

> ```
> public String aID { get; set;}
> public PageReference onCreateNew(){
>    return new PageReference('/a0W/e?saveURL=%2Fapex%2FOpptProdEngineeringEdit?id=' +
>    ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id') + '%26passID%3D' +
>    aID +'&cancelURL=%2Fapex%2FOpptProdEngineeringEdit?id=' +
>    ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('Id') +
>    '&RecordType=012g00000000JWI'); 
> }
> ```

This section of my controller:

> ```
> '%26passID%3D' + aID
> ```
>
> is where I'm trying to pass the ID of "a" in the saveurl... but no matter what I  do it is returning null. Any suggestions?

Comment: Unencoded question mark in the URL for a start... `'/a0W/e?saveURL=%2Fapex%2FOpptProdEngineeringEdit?id='`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Not sure if it is still an issue, but here is a link to a blog post from a few years back claiming that CommandButton doesn't actually invoke the setter.

http://blog.jeffdouglas.com/2010/03/04/passing-parameters-with-a-commandbutton/

He brings up 2 recommendations:

- use CommandLink and style it to look like a CommandButton
- rerender a hidden PageBlock section (which apparently invokes the setter)

Comment: Thank you! This does appear to still be an issue, I just tested it out by switching CommandButton to CommandLink to try it out and it works fine now. I'll give that restyling a try. Thanks again!